# realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000002119010

Tags: c, memory, malloc, realloc

When I compile and run this code, I get an error. The error message is:

`realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000002119010`

The file `input` has about 4000 words.

I debugged it, but I can not find any problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF_LEN 10   //buf length

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int file_d;                     //file descriptor
  char *ct_head;                  //content_first_char
  char *content;
  ssize_t read_len = BUF_LEN;     //had read length
  int mem_block_count = 0;

  file_d = open("input", O_RDONLY);

  if (file_d < 0)
    {
      perror("open");
      exit (1);
    }

  content = ct_head = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUF_LEN);
  mem_block_count = 1;

  while (read_len == BUF_LEN)
    {
      read_len = read(file_d, ct_head, BUF_LEN);
      if (read_len < 0)
        {
          perror("read");
          exit(2);
        }
      if (read_len == BUF_LEN)
        {
          ct_head = (char *)realloc(content, sizeof(char) *(++mem_block_count));
          ct_head = &content[(mem_block_count-1) * BUF_LEN];
        }
      else
        ct_head[read_len] = '\0';
    }
  printf("%s", content);

  close(file_d);
  free(content);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `realloc`, shouldn't it be `(char *)realloc(content, sizeof(char) *(++mem_block_count) * BUF_LEN);`?

Comment: After your realloc, content may be invalid (since it may have been freed by the realloc). I think you should assign the pointer returned by realloc to content, not ct_head

Comment: Be careful, [do not cast the return type of your malloc/realloc functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1151654).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is but these lines:

```
    ct_head = (char *)realloc(content, sizeof(char) *(++mem_block_count));
    ct_head = &content[(mem_block_count-1) * BUF_LEN];
```

Are very dodgy. After the first line, `ct_head` points to the realloced block and `content` points to garbage. Then the second line reads `content` and re-assigns `ct_head` - leaking the realloced memory.

I suspect you may just have memory corruption in your program?

I think

```
ct_head = (char *)realloc(content, sizeof(char) *(++mem_block_count));
```

should be:

```
content = (char *)realloc(content, sizeof(char) *(++mem_block_count) * BUF_LEN);
if (content == NULL)
{
    // do something if the realloc fails
}
```

Comment: YES, It works.. I'm won't make this mistake again!thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first time you use realloc, it allocates only 2 bytes because, going into the call, `sizeof(char)` is 1 and `mem_block_count` is also 1 (and it is then pre-incremented to 2).

This means the next read will overrun the buffer it has allocated. I suspect you need to also multiply by `BUF_LEN` in your realloc.

**Edit**

I've just realised, it's even worse: straight after allocating content to 2 bytes, you set `ct_head` to `BUF_LEN` bytes beyond the start of content.  This means your read overwrites an area that is totally outside the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got some good answers here, but here's a little bit of advice that won't fit in a comment. In C, `sizeof(char)` is ***always*** 1. It is 1 by definition, so it is as redundant as using `(1 * BUF_LEN)`. Also in C, you don't have to [and shouldn't] cast the result of `malloc`. Doing so can mask a fundamental error<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to allocate space depending on the size of a type, use:

```
ct_head = malloc(sizeof(*ct_head) * BUF_LEN);
```

That way, if the type of `ct_head` changes, you'll still be allocating enough space, without having to change all the calls to `malloc` and `realloc`.

<sub>1. If you do not include the appropriate header for `malloc`, then a C compiler will assume that `malloc` returns `int`, and this may cause issues on platforms where the size of an `int` differs from the size of a pointer type. Also, conversions from integer types to pointer types are implementation-defined.</sub>